# All Sitecore 8.2.x Azure Topologies seem to be effected because of TLS issues

Tags: azure

In any Sitecore 8.2.x when using Experience Analytics when opening up chrome debugging there appears to be an error around TLS, there would be the same error when .Net code will be calling another location.

This is the error log:

> Exception System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was
>   closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @ChrisAuer just added it, thanks for contributing.. i am part of product at Sitecore and we are getting out the answer quickly.. KB article coming soon as well..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Solutions***

**Existing Installations**

Please unzip Sitecore package, published as release artifact here and find the patch and bin and include them within your solution

**New Installations**

We have upgraded the arm templates to include a wdp fix

Changes includes:

1. ARM templates, available from top of repo
   https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates
2. Sitecore package, published as release artifact here

**More Information**

Microsoft disabled support of TLS 1.0 on App Services recently (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9dace9cb-a1a8-4f77-af26-324bc2b6740e/tls-plans-for-azure-app-service?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview[enter link description here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#if-your-app-targets-a-net-framework-version-earlier-than-47))

Technical details can be found here:  [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#if-your-app-targets-a-net-framework-version-earlier-than-47)

TLDR; If you are not setting specific TLS version from the code, then you just need to check .Net version used for standalone Web Apps (not the code you install on top of Sitecore):

1. .Net 3.5 – 4.5.2 (Sitecore 8.2.X) - Explicit setting of TLS version required. That’s how we did this for SXP.
2. 4.6 - 4.6.2 (Sitecore 9.0-9.0.2) - Need to be tested on your solution. We haven’t found any issues with SXP.
3. 4.7 and above - No actions required

   *Please Note: This is not a problem in versions 9.x*

Comment: And here is the kb article https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/688903

Comment: Does .Net framework refer to what is used with the web app in Azure (portal) or the target framework in Sitecore web.config? Kindly clarify